# MobileVLCKit play TCP/RTSP stream on iOS (iphone)

Tags: ios, iphone, tcp, vlc, rtsp

I'm here to use MobileVLCKit to play rtsp tcp stream, but it won't play it, is there any way to play? I searche VLC forum about it, but there's several questions post but nobody give a correct answer, and mentions that pass param "--rtsp-tcp", I tried it with below

`NSArray *options = @[@"--extraintf=", @"--rtsp-tcp"];
self.mediaPlayer = [[VLCMediaPlayer alloc]initWithOptions:options];`

and my app just crashed. 


So what should I do? 

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I tried build my app with this option again but it didn't crash, and play TCP/RTSP well, it's wired, maybe my MobileVLCKit framework isn't stable or Xcode played joke on me, anyway it's working fun now...